# puppet-logstash module produces a blank logstash.conf

Tags: puppet, logstash

I am probably confused on the proper usage.

I have setup the configuration of my shipper using Hiera:

```
classes:
  - os::repo
  - profiles::logstash::shipper

logstash::configfile:
   'input_file':
      content: '/etc/puppet/modules/profiles/manifests/logstash/templates/input_file.erb'
      order:   '10'
```

My profiles::logstash::shipper is setup as:

```
class profiles::logstash::shipper() {
  class { 'logstash':
    ensure  => 'present',
    version => '1.4.1-1_bd507eb',
    status  => 'enabled',
  }

  include logstash
}
```

input_file.erb:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "syslog"
    path => ["/var/log/secure", "/var/log/messages", "/var/log/syslog"]
    exclude => ["*.gz", "shipper.log"]
    sincedb_path => "/var/run/logstash/lssincedbs"
  }

  file {
    type => "logfile"
    path => ["/tmp/*.log"]
    sincedb_path => "/var/run/logstash/lssincedbs"
  }
}
```

(I know this technically isn't an erb but it will be eventually)

Every time puppet agent does a catalog run, it produces an empty `logstash.conf` in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` on my agent acting as a shipper.

What did I do wrong? I am probably confused as I didn't understand something in the github documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this hiera value

```
logstash::configfile:
  'input_file':
    content: '/etc/puppet/modules/profiles/manifests/logstash/templates/input_file.erb'
    order:   '10'
```

does **not** implicitly create this resource

```
logstash::configfile { 'input_file': content => '...', order => 10 }
```

It *would* do so if you added this invocation to your manifest

```
create_resources('logstash::configfile', hiera('logstash::configfile'))
```

but

1. that would be a rather confusing naming scheme in hiera and more importantly
2. it will not Just Work once you *do* want Puppet to interpret your template with ERB code

If it is an option, move the configfile from Hiera to your manifest proper.

Comment: Thanks.. I think I am going to go to ERB and just pass in parameters.